# Error:Installing DataStax Enterprise 5.0 on RHEL-based systems using Yum

Tags: google-compute-engine, datastax-enterprise

I fellow [the tutotial](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installRHELdse.html) step by step.
When running `sudo yum -y install dse-full`, I got the following log with errors:

```
sudo yum -y install dse-full
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dse-full.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libtomcat = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libhadoop2-client = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libspark = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libhadoop = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libhive = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libsqoop = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libsolr = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libgraph = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libcassandra = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libmahout = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-liblog4j = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libpig = 5.0.6 for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dse.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: which for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: procps for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-full.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libcassandra.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
Error: Package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) >= 2.6 for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libgraph.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libhadoop.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dse-libhadoop-native = 5.0.6 for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libhadoop2-client.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: glibc for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libhive.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-liblog4j.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libmahout.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libpig.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libsolr.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libspark.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libsqoop.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libtomcat.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dse.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: which for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: procps for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-full.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libcassandra.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) >= 2.6 for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libgraph.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libhadoop.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libhadoop-native.x86_64 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc for package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64
---> Package dse-libhadoop2-client.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: glibc for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libhive.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-liblog4j.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libmahout.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libpig.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libsolr.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libspark.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libsqoop.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
---> Package dse-libtomcat.noarch 0:5.0.6-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: shadow-utils for package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/env for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: procps
Error: Package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/bash
Error: Package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: python(abi) >= 2.6
Error: Package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-full-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: which
Error: Package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /usr/bin/env
Error: Package: dse-libgraph-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/bash
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64 (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/bash
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64 (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libcassandra-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /usr/bin/env
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop2-client-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: glibc
Error: Package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libhadoop-native-5.0.6-1.x86_64 (datastax)
           Requires: glibc
Error: Package: dse-libmahout-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /usr/bin/env
Error: Package: dse-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-liblog4j-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/bash
Error: Package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/bash
Error: Package: dse-libsolr-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libsqoop-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
Error: Package: dse-libtomcat-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /bin/sh
Error: Package: dse-libhive-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /usr/bin/env
Error: Package: dse-libpig-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: /usr/bin/env
Error: Package: dse-libspark-5.0.6-1.noarch (datastax)
           Requires: shadow-utils
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I trid the instructions the log said. It didn't work.

**My Environment**:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS(on google compute engine)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a problem Datastax is having with their YUM repo.  If you check http://rpm.datastax.com/community/ you'll find either that repodata/ is missing or empty.  It needs to be there and contain some repo-describing metadata.

Some one reported this on the DS Academy Slack channel yesterday.  I noted it again this morning.  Hopefully they fix it soon.

**UPDATE** Got ahold of Datastax.  This has been resolved now.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. I get the similar errors, though the directory isn't empty now.